# interval in Doctrine2

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I need to fetch Entities from database which are updated 15 minutes from now. I tried something like this:

```
$entityManager->createQuery("
    SELECT t FROM \Trip t
    WHERE
        t.dateUpdated > (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() - INTERVAL ?1 MINUTES)
");
```

But this obviously failed, because Doctrine does not support INTERVAL.

I have different timezones on application & database servers, so I need to use database date function and cannot use `new DateTime('-15 minutes')` in PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

INTERVAL is not supported by the Doctrine Lexter because Doctrine was built to be as generic as possible, so that it would be compatible with a lot of database vendors.

In some cases this is not ideal because you cannot make use of vendor-specific functions (like INTERVAL) in your DQL, so you would have to either write vendor-specific SQL or adding the function you want to Doctrine.

You can register your functions adding them to the ORM configuration in `vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Configuration.php` in your Symfony web root:

```
<?php
$config = new \Doctrine\ORM\Configuration();
$config->addCustomStringFunction($name, $class);
$config->addCustomNumericFunction($name, $class);
$config->addCustomDatetimeFunction($name, $class);

$em = EntityManager::create($dbParams, $config);
```

The `$name` is the name the function will be referred to in the DQL query. `$class` is a string of a class-name which has to extend Doctrine\ORM\Query\Node\FunctionNode. This is a class that offers all the necessary API and methods to implement a user defined function.

You can find specific examples on how to do this [here](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/cookbook/dql-user-defined-functions.html)

**Method 2. Writing SQL**

In some cases is just easier to write SQL in Symfony using Doctrine's PDO wrapper this way:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$query = "SELECT 1";
$stmt = $em->getConnection()->query($query);
$results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

or if your query is parametrized:

```
$foo = 1;
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$query = "SELECT :foo";
$stmt = $em->getConnection()->prepare($query);
$stmt->bindParam(':foo', $foo, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Also, if you don't want to put too much "fat" in your controllers, you can create a Custom Repository in Symfony, so that your complex DQL/SQL are separated from your main program.

you can read more about custom repositories [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#custom-repository-classes)

Comment: Thanks, I used Method 1. and created custom Function. Second Method is returning only arrays and not entities, is that right?

Comment: That's right, it only returns arrays/objects but it doesn't return entities. You can get the entities afterwards if you have the id and use something like `$this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('yourBundle:yourEntity)->find($result['entityId']);`